# Stop the video in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I imported the flv video into movieclip.
How can i stop the video by clicking in work area?
The viewer should be able to pause the video not only by clicking onto the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the video is in the movieclip, with a movieclip timeline as long as the video ?
If so you could do :

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var isPaused:Boolean = false;
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);


function onClick(evt:MouseEvent){
    if (isPaused){
        mc.stop();
    }else{
        mc.play();
    }
    isPaused = !isPaused;
}
```